# How to populate multiple textboxes from a row in gridview that uses a link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm trying to populate multiple text boxes with data from a gridview when I click the link button (which is in fact the name of one of the fields in each row) but it isn't going through. I'm new to this - literally my first time. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[index];

        AccountNumber.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        Name.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        Address1.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        Address2.Text = selectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        Address3.Text = selectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        PhoneNumber.Text = selectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
        FaxNumber.Text= selectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
        CurrencyID.Text = selectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
    }
}
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="Agent_Account_No" 
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor ="Lavender" 
              HeaderStyle-BackColor="#9966FF" 
              AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black"    
              HorizontalAlign="Center" 
              RowStyle-BorderColor="Black" 
              EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."  
              onrowcommand ="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField datafield="Agent_Account_No" HeaderText="Account No" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" 
                        ItemStyle-Width="50" 
                        SortExpression="Agent_Account_No" 
                        ReadOnly="true"> 
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
                       Width="50px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Agent_Name">
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:LinkButton ID="AgentName" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Agent_Name") %>' 
                                CommandName="Select" 
                                CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Agent_Name") %>'> 
                </asp:LinkButton> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Please explain what - "isn't going through" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using `TemplateField`s for all of your columns, like this:

Markup:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account No" SortExpression="Agent_Account_No">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:Label ID="LabelAccountNumber" runat="server" 
                       Text='<%# Eval("Agent_Account_No") %>'>
            </asp:Label> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    ...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Agent_Name">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:LinkButton ID="AgentName" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Agent_Name") %>' 
                            CommandName="Select" 
                            CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Agent_Name") %>'>
            </asp:LinkButton> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Now in the `RowCommand` method, you can use the `FindControl()` method of the grid view row to get to the text you are interested in, like this:

Code-behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.CommandName == "Select") 
    { 
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 
        GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[index];

        // Find the account number label to get the text value for the text box
        Label theAccountNumberLabel = selectedRow.FindControl("LabelAccountNumber") as Label;

        // Make sure we found the label before we try to use it
        if(theAccountNumberLabel != null)
        {
            AccountNumber.Text = theAccountNumberLabel.Text;
        }
        // Follow the same pattern for the other labels to get other text values          
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks alot for the immediate response.  i got it working using some other code on the site. however now the updatepanel itself is displaying two textboxes. one with the value clicked on and an empty one. please see that new question. thanks alot!!

Comment: @New2This - glad I was able to help, feel free to up-vote this answer as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work this way - using help from this site:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;        

    AccountNumber.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Agent_Account_No"].ToString();

    ......
}
```

I don't know if this declaration is right, but it works. However now that it works I see a problem that I didn't see before - see my profile and thanks a lot!